# Small calculation in Max entropy

Tags: mathematical-statistics, entropy, derivative

I am wondering where the -1 comes from in the derivatives with respect to the probability.

For example, [these notes](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Maximum_Entropy_Property_Gaussian.html).

For the basic example with the uniform distribution.

We want to minimze $[-\int p(x)\log(p(x))dx+\lambda(\int p(x)-1)]$

so we take derivatives with respect to $p(x)$

So I see where we would have $-\log(p(x))+\lambda$

But I am missing a -1 term, ie it should be

$-\log(p(x))-1+\lambda$

I think it is just something simple I am missing, can anyone help me to see what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is variational analysis but it resembles classical calculus. Remember that when you take the derivative of $x lnx$, you will have $lnx + x \frac{1}{x}=lnx+1$.